# Code 204 - Error while creating Webhook URL for twitter account in php

Tags: php, twitter, webhooks

I am using twitter account activity api's to send/receive messages. In it i am facing problem in generating webhook. First time it was created successfully. In webhook file i am saving messages in database when each time message sent or received. But when I sent message nothing goes in database. Here is **webhook** file:

```
const APP_CONSUMER_SECRET = '**********';
// Example token provided by incoming GET request
if(isset($_REQUEST['crc_token'])) {
    $token = $_REQUEST['crc_token'];

    /**
     * Creates a HMAC SHA-256 hash created from the app TOKEN and
     * your app Consumer Secret.
     * @param  token  the token provided by the incoming GET request
     * @return string
     */
    function get_challenge_response($token) {
      $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $token, APP_CONSUMER_SECRET, true);
      $response = array(
        'response_token' => 'sha256=' . base64_encode($hash)
      );
      return json_encode($response);
    }
}else{
    
    $feedData = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $handleData = fopen('twitterDemo.txt', "w" );
    fwrite($handleData,$feedData);
    fclose($handleData);
    $array = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    if (isset($array['direct_message_events'][0]['type']) && $array['direct_message_events'][0]['type'] == 'message_create' ) {
        include_once ('config.php');
        include_once ('database-queries.php');
        $message = $array['direct_message_events'][0]['message_create']['message_data']['text'];
        $sender = $array['direct_message_events'][0]['message_create']['sender_id'];
        $from = $array['direct_message_events'][0]['message_create']['target']['recipient_id'];
        $message_type = 'incoming';
        $message_status = 'unread';
        $userId = $sender;
        $account_name = 'twitter';
        $image_url = '';
        if(isset($array['direct_message_events'][0]['message_create']['message_data']['attachment'])){
                $image_url = "Not Image";
        }
        
        $data = array('to'=>$from, 'from'=>$sender, 'msg'=>$message,'image_url' =>$image_url);
        insert($data, $account_name, $message_type, $message_status, $conn);
    }
}
```

I thought there might be webhook problem so i deleted the existing app and create new one and set development environment label for it with new name. But for it when i tried to create webhook it gives me error:

> [code] => 214 [message] => Webhook URL does not meet the requirements.
> Invalid CRC token or json response format.

I dont know whats happening here now. I am using this api to create webhook url

```
$url = "https://example.com/twitter/webhook.php";
$result = $connection->post("account_activity/all/env_name/webhooks", ["url" => $url]);
```

Can anyone please help me this out. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error message.
The problem seem to be that the
i`f(isset($_REQUEST['crc_token']))`
is not working anymore. Though the token is set. I don't know what is causing the problem but when I let the code just fetch the $_REQUEST['crc_token'] and create and print the hash its working.

But I see your code is not calling the get_challenge_response($token) function.
I think

```
print get_challenge_response($token)
```

may help? If the Webhook was deactivated by twitter you have to initiate another CRC check:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/guides/securing-webhooks

Your app can also trigger a CRC when needed by making a PUT request with your webhook id. Triggering a CRC is useful as you develop your webhook application, after deploying new code and restarting your service.

Comment: thanks @user7100414 for your response. Well, I already solved this problem.

Comment: @SukhpalSingh What was the solution i got the same response what you have shared